# Filter by non field in Django

Tags: python, django, filter

I want to filter by a non field column in the admin page of a django app. For example I could have the following:

```
class Subject(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class School(models.Model)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)

    def subject(self)
        return self.student.subject.name
```

The I would have the following in admin.py

```
class SchoolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('school', 'student', 'subject')
  list_filter = ('school', 'student', 'subject')

admin.site.register(School, SchoolAdmin)
```

However this wouldn't work as I am unable to filter on subject since it does not refer to a field? Does anyone know of the best way of doing this? By searching around it looks like SimpleListFilter may do the trick but I am new to python and django and cannot work out how to implement this for my example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could also do: `list_filter = (..., student__subject__name)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
class SchoolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('school', 'student__name', 'student__subject__name')
  list_filter = ('school', 'student__name', 'student__subject__name')

admin.site.register(School, SchoolAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew there would be a simple solution! It won't let me accept the answer yet but I will do that when I can